# How to use rand() for big numbers

Tags: php

How can I generate a number not exceeding a specific range?

Example:

I want to generate a number that has 70 digits but doesn't exceed "90000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

How to do that?

I tried using gmp_init

```
$range1 = gmp_init("100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
$range2 = gmp_init("900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000");

$generatedValue = rand($range1,$range2);

echo $generatedValue;
```

However, it outputs the following error:

> PHP Warning:  rand() expects parameter 1 to be int, object given

I tried rand(), mt_rand(), random_byte()...

Another Try:

```
<?php

$rand1 = gmp_random_range(100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000>
    
    echo gmp_strval($rand1) . "\n";
```

> Error: PHP Warning:  gmp_random_range(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type in /home/ubuntu/test/test5.php on line

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-random-range.php

Comment: Thank you, I've just tried that but it didn't work, please check my question Edit

Comment: Your function call to `gmp_random_range` uses an opening parenthesis but closes with an angle bracket (>). Is this an error in your posting or your actual code?

Comment: @parttimeturtle thank you for your reply, it's actually the code, i'm following the example from this link php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-random-range.php as suggested by Jarred

Comment: @parttimeturtle I've just checked what you mentioned carefully, you are seeing `>` because the number is too long when I copied it from the terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's clear up a few points of confusion:

- PHP's native integers have a maximum of 2 to the power of 63, because they are stored in 64 bits of memory, and the 64th bit is used for negative numbers (I'm simplifying slightly). No matter where you put it in the source code, a larger number than that simply can't exist as a PHP integer, not even briefly.
- GMP is a library which stores numbers a different way, and *can* represent numbers higher than that. But it can't see what you put in the source code, you have to pass it some other value that PHP *can* represent, which is why GMP functions accept strings as well as integers.
- Normal PHP functions don't know about GMP - you can't pass a GMP number object to normal mathematical or other functions, you have to use the functions in the GMP library. (There is an exception, which is that you can use operators like + and * with GMP objects, and PHP calls the appropriate function for you.)

Bearing all that in mind, we can look at [the list of GMP functions in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php), and find [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-random-range.php):

> gmp_random_range(GMP|int|string $min, GMP|int|string $max): GMP

Just what we need! Note that it can take arguments of three different types:

- Integers, which are no good in our case, because we can't create integers big enough
- GMP objects, like the ones you created with gmp_init
- Strings, like you used to create the GMP objects

So the simplest way to write your example is:

```
$rand1 = gmp_random_range('100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000','900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000');
```

This will return a GMP object, so you'll need to look for other GMP functions to decide what to do with it next.

Comment: Thanks alot, your solution worked right away I only had to add an echo :)
 `$rand1 = gmp_random_range('100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000','900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000');
    echo $rand1;`

Answer (score 0):

Numbers in php - and most programming languages - has max and min values you can not go beyond.
Maximum integer in php defined in PHP_INT_MAX , Maximum float defined in PHP_FLOAT_MAX.

But if you want a random string larger than this maximum number bounds. You can string concatenation many random numbers to get this random string:

```
$largeRandomString = mt_rand(10000000, 99999999).mt_rand(10000000, 99999999).mt_rand(10000000, 99999999).mt_rand(10000000, 99999999);
```

Comment: This will lead to some odd biases. For instance, it can never generate a number with more than seven zeroes in a row, because each part will always start with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, or 9. You could *possibly* sort that out by using ranges starting at zero and using sprintf to make them fixed width ... but if you have access to GMP (which we know the OP does), you'll be better off leaving that to do it all for you.

Comment: But if all we need is a large random string, It is better if we achieve this without installing external library.
About the issue you mentioned, I think it is not suitable using sprintf to make this a fixed width since it will produce a string with a lot of zeros. In this case we can do this: substr(mt_rand(10000000, 99999999),1)

Comment: @M3Ali gmp_random_range already did the job my friend :)

Comment: @M3Ali The string of zeroes *needs* to be possible for all except the first "chunk" of the string, so that outputs like 123000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 are possible. Both my suggestion and yours would achieve that, in different ways, but the code in your answer would not.

Comment: @IMSoP I mean if we start from zero and use sprintf to make the string fixed width, we get a lot of numbers smaller than 10000000, all these numbers will completed with zeros to be the same length, all these extra zeros are not randomly inserted.
And yes the code in my answer can't give the 1230000..... ,but the fix I suggest in the comment may solve this issue.

Comment: @M3Ali They're just as randomly inserted as the zeroes after the 1 when you start at 10000000: rand(0, 9999999) might give you 42; rand(10000000, 9999999) might give you 10000042; both have equal probability (1 in 10000000), and both could be used to generate the digits '0000042' in the middle of a longer string (the first by padding as I suggested, the second by stripping off the first digit, as you suggested).

Comment: @IMSop No, If we start with zero as you suggest, we will give the multipliers of 10 more probability than other numbers. We will get numbers end with 0 more than other numbers. but if we do my suggest in the comment the numbers seems to be more randomly selected

Comment: @M3Ali I think maybe you've misunderstood my suggestion. I'm saying that '42' should be padded *on the left* to become '0000042'. There won't be any extra numbers *ending* in zero, only the numbers *beginning* in zero, which are what we wanted.

Comment: @M3Ali your solution doesn't allow to specify a valid range. For example to generate a number between 2 big numbers like 50000000000000000000000000000000000 & 6000000000000000000000000000 .... your suggested code will simply output a specific number over and over and concatenate the whole number in a single line which doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

This solution generates a string with a fixed length of 70 characters and evenly spaced digits from 0 to 9. Only basic PHP functions are required. The algorithm must be modified for 32-bit systems.

```
$min = "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";  
$max = '9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
do{
  for($str = "", $i=0; $i < 7; $i++){
    $str .= sprintf("%010d",mt_rand(0,9999999999));
  }
}while($str < $min OR $str > $max);

var_dump($str);
//string(70) "8225821562698285549247617814952633507395510882337701683734245940552330"
```

The range filter is based on a simple string comparison. For this, $min and $max must contain exactly 70 characters.

Comment: To fit the requirements in the question perfectly, the lowest number generated should be '100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', rather than '000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001' (=== `1`, which doesn't have 70 digits). For instance, you could generate the first digit from 1 to 9, then tweak your solution to generate the remaining 69.

Comment: @IMSoP : I updated the code.